# How to check current environment is spring container?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I designed a component that collects application runtime data, which is sent to the analysis server via Kafka. In most cases, apps will integrate Kafka. In order to avoid connect to same Kafka twice, I need to determine whether the app uses Kafka. If the app uses Kafka, I directly reuse the connections.

So, how can I predict app uses kafka ?

And if app integrate `spring-kafka`， what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

> avoid connect to same Kafka twice,

There should be no issue with this. Clients are lightweight enough to create more than one of them in one app, from one machine, etc

> determine whether the app uses Kafka.

Beyond decompilation, if it's a fat jar, you can `jar -tf app.jar | grep -i Kafka`, however this would only tell you there's files with the word "Kafka" in the package, not necessarily that any *Apache Kafka clients* are in use